# Making panel or groupbox visible throws Argumentoutofrangeexception

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have a MVC winform app in vb.net,

There is a BaseController which has a reference to a Model, and 2 concreteControllers inherit from this BaseController.

Before `InitializeComponent()` one controller is instantiated, then InitializeComponent is called and afterwards, some bindings like this one:

```
chkGeolocalizacion.DataBindings.Add("Checked", controller.Model, "SolicitarGeolocalizacion", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

chkGeolocalizacion is inside a groupbox or panel (tried both).

Then the Form waits for user input to choose between 2 radio buttons and an event is triggered, which replaces the controller with the one the user chose. Afterwards I want to make visible the groupbox which has the controls binded and Argumentoutofrangeexception is thrown, with something like "value 0 is not between minimum and maximum".

The code works flawlessly if I never modify the visible property.

```
Dim modelo As Model_Reporte = controller.Model
If rbtScoringDistancia.Checked Then
    controller = New Reporte_controller_SinK()
    chkGeolocalizacion.Visible = True
Else
    controller = New Reporte_Controller(Me)
    chkGeolocalizacion.Visible = False
End If
controller.Model = modelo
pnlConfig.Visible = True
```

Is this a .net bug or what? I couldn't make it work and the only workaround is to make visible/invisible the controls and not the groupbox or panel that contains them

(I tried with both panel and groupbox, same exception thrown)

Thanks!

ps: if you need to see more of my code ask for it.

edit: Adding extra code

```
Public Class Reporte

Private controller As Reporte_ControllerBase

Public Sub New()
    controller = New Reporte_Controller(Me)
    InitializeComponent()
    addDataBindings()
End Sub

Private Sub addDataBindings()
    dt_fecha_desde.DataBindings.Add("Value", controller.Model, "GetFechaDesde", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    dt_fecha_hasta.DataBindings.Add("Value", controller.Model, "GetFechaHasta", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    KM_Scoring.DataBindings.Add("Value", controller.Model, "KM_Scoring", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    chkGeolocalizacion.DataBindings.Add("Checked", controller.Model, "SolicitarGeolocalizacion", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
End Sub

Private Sub rbtScoringDistancia_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles rbtScoringDistancia.CheckedChanged, rbtScoringAlternativo.CheckedChanged
    Dim modelo As Model_Reporte = controller.Model
    If rbtScoringDistancia.Checked Then
        lblKm.Text = "Iteraciones"
        LblScoring.Text = "Considerar infracción a las "
        controller = New Reporte_controller_SinK()
        chkGeolocalizacion.Visible = True
    Else
        LblScoring.Text = "Evaluar scoring cada "
        lblKm.Text = "Kilómetros"
        controller = New Reporte_Controller(Me)
        chkGeolocalizacion.Visible = False
    End If
    controller.Model = modelo
    pnlConfig.Visible = True 'Exception thrown here
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Reporte_Controller
     Inherits Reporte_ControllerBase
'extra code...
 End Class


Public MustInherit class Reporte_ControllerBase
Protected modelo As Model_Reporte = New Model_Reporte


Public Property Model() As Model_Reporte
    Get
        Return modelo
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Model_Reporte)
        modelo = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class

Public Class Model_Reporte

    Private _getFechaDesde As Date = Date.Today.AddMonths(-1)
    Private _getfechaHasta As Date = Date.Today
    Private _kmScoring As Integer
    Private _solicitarGeolocalizacion As Boolean
    Private _limiteRegular As Int32 = 7
    Private _limiteMal As Int32 = 25

'getters and setters for each property
End Class
```

to clarify: Everything works except making the panel visible property on true if I set it false before. If it is true and I don't modify it, it works.

edit2: The exception is only thrown when making visible = true on panels or groupbox which have several controls binded to the model of a controller. Making visible = true or false on another groupbox which contains controls NOT binded works flawlessly.

Comment: At **what line** exactly does it crash? Throw in the exception, that will help us debug it.

Comment: pnlConfig.Visible = True  

The exception text is  

"El valor de '0' no es válido para 'Value'. 'Value' debería estar entre 'Minimum' y 'Maximum'.
Nombre del parámetro: Value"

What translates to "Value 0 is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'Maximum' and 'Minimum' what doesn't makes sense for property Visible

Comment: Have you **disabled** `pnlconfig`somewhere earlier? This might be causing your problem. Something along that : `pnlconfig.enable = false`

Comment: Nope, enable is always set on true from the designer, and I never modify that property

Comment: Mind throwing in the rest of your code? Because so far what you have shown is flawless.

Comment: I edited the original post

Comment: Have you tried binding the command to a button? Just to see if it works alone? Something along : `if pnlConfig.visible = true then pnlConfig.visible = false else pnlConfig.visible = true end` (trigger by a `button.click`. If this bugs, then I'm clueless.

Comment: still throws exception

http://i.imgur.com/OFgi1DH.png

Comment: Something's fishy... Sorry I can't help you anymore, something in the form is causing this bug, I can't recreate it on my computer (it works on my computer). Be sure that nothing is wrapping the Panel, this may be causing this bug also(?). Good luck either way! (+1 for visibility)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error by adding the databinding in the form_load event rather than adding them in the new (after InitializeComponents() is called). It's weird I know but this solved the issue.

Comment: The `InitializeComponent()` method shall always be the first to be called in a `Windows Form` constructor as it is the method responsible to create all of the other controls on a form.

Comment: yeah, but some weird things happened...like InitializeComponent() triggered some events that required the controller to be instanced before (The projects follows a MVC scheme) anyway, in this case, If I put the same exacto code under InitializeComponent, the bug appears, but if I put that code under the form_load, the bug dissapears...weird.

Comment: There's nothing weird about that. The `Form Load Event` occurs just before the form is displayed for the first time, that means that every controls of the form has been initialized correctly and are ready to be accessed. If you put your code right after the call to `InitializeComponents()`, and some undesired events are triggered unwillingly, just add the event handlers after your code instead of setting them into the Property Explorer.

Comment: So putting code after    InitializeComponents() doesn't ensures me all controls have been instanciated?

Comment: Not necessarily, you're right. In a `Form` constructor, you want to put event handlers in place, and initialize any helper members or the like that you know you are the sole proprietor.

Comment: For further details on the order of events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx